# insert a column into a tabular object

Tags: r, tabular

I found this blog on getting a nested table into LaTeX format[(Blog Link)](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/01/printing-nested-tables-in-r-bridging-between-the-reshape-and-tables-packages/).  I like the outcome but want to insert a column into the object at the beginning after the rownames.  I'm used to dealing with data frames so dealing with this beast is more difficult than typical column indexing.

Here's what I have now:

```
          pre         post       
 approach mean  sd    mean  sd   
 1        24.17 8.310 54.33 11.01
 2        25.50 9.434 65.25 16.32
 3        26.33 9.139 63.17 12.53
```

And here's what I'd like it to look like:

```
             pre         post       
 approach n  mean  sd    mean  sd   
 1        12 24.17 8.310 54.33 11.01
 2        12 25.50 9.434 65.25 16.32
 3        12 26.33 9.139 63.17 12.53
```

Here's the dput of z and also the column of n's I'd like to insert.

Thank you in advance.

```
z <- structure(list(24.1666666666667, 25.5, 26.3333333333333, 8.31027111835746, 
    9.4339811320566, 9.13866245766587, 54.3333333333333, 65.25, 
    63.1666666666667, 11.0068848977136, 16.3157759685081, 12.5323822978956), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("term", "term", "term", "term")), rowLabels = structure(c("1", 
"2", "3"), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "approach"), justification = structure(c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), .Dim = c(3L, 1L)), colnamejust = NA_character_, justify = NA, suppress = 0), colLabels = structure(c("pre", 
"mean", NA, "sd", "post", "mean", NA, "sd"), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), justification = structure(c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), .Dim = c(2L, 4L)), colnamejust = character(0), justify = NA, suppress = 0), table = value * 
    v * approach ~ variable2 * result_variable, formats = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("format", "format", "format", "format"))), justification = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("justification", "justification", "justification", 
    "justification"))), class = "tabular")

structure(c(12L, 12L, 12L), .Names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: I'd like to actually understand the structure of this for future needs.

Comment: Did you try the `structure` you posted?  It does give me the data.frame you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only (known ?) way is to re-assign re-ordered:

```
R> mockup <- data.frame(B=21:23, C=31:33)
R> mockup
   B  C
1 21 31
2 22 32
3 23 33
R>
```

Now add column A:

```
R> mockup[,"A"] <- 1:3
R> mockup
   B  C A
1 21 31 1
2 22 32 2
3 23 33 3
R>
```

And reorder:

```
R> mockup <- mockup[,c("A", "B", "C")]
R> mockup
  A  B  C
1 1 21 31
2 2 22 32
3 3 23 33
R>
```

*Presto*.  New column at the beginning.

Comment: I did the the `str`, saw list and tried some list indexing `[[]]` and it wasn't working.  `?tabular` didn't work and I assumed (incorrectly) that it wasn't a data.frame object (forgetting a data.frame is a list).  Works perfectly, definitely a doof moment for me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
z <- data.frame(approach = gl(3, 12), pre = rnorm(36)*50, post = rnorm(36)*60)
library(tables)
tabular(approach ~ (pre + post) * (mean + sd))

      pre          post         
approach mean   sd    mean    sd   
1        -5.431 61.01   3.766 54.76
2        20.408 29.14  -9.261 54.58
3        -7.854 53.55 -30.046 62.41
tabular(approach ~ (n=1) + (pre + post) * (mean + sd))

    pre          post         
approach n  mean   sd    mean    sd   
1        12 -5.431 61.01   3.766 54.76
2        12 20.408 29.14  -9.261 54.58
3        12 -7.854 53.55 -30.046 62.41
tabular(approach + 1 ~ (n=1) + (pre + post) * (mean + sd))

    pre          post         
approach n  mean   sd    mean    sd   
1        12 -5.431 61.01   3.766 54.76
2        12 20.408 29.14  -9.261 54.58
3        12 -7.854 53.55 -30.046 62.41
All      36  2.374 50.06 -11.847 57.46
```

For more details see [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) of the `tables` package.